# Building a collaborative filtering recommendation engine using Spark mlLib

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, collaborative-filtering

I am trying to build a recommendation engine based on collaborative filtering using apache Spark. I have been able to run the `recommendation_example.py` on my data, with quite good result. (`MSE` ~ 0.9). Some of the specific questions that I have are:

1. How to make recommendation for the users who have not done any activity on the site. Isn't there some API call for popular items, which would give me the most popular items based on user actions. One way to do is to identify the popular items by ourselves, and catch the `java.util.NoSuchElementException` exception, and return those popular items.
2. How to reload the model, after some data has been added in the input file. I am trying to reload the model using another function, which tries to save the model, but it gives error as `org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException`. One way to do is to listen for the incoming data on a parallel thread, save it using `model.save(sc, "target/tmp/<some target>")` and then reload the model after significant data has been received. I am lost here, how to achieve that.

It would be very helpful, if I could get some direction here.

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, you can find item_id, Number of times that item_id appeared. You can use map and reduceByKey functions of spark for that. After that find the top 10/20 items having max count. You can also give the weightage depending on recency of the items.

For the second part, you can save the model with new name every time. I generally create a folder name on the go using the current date and time and use the same name to reload the model from the saved folder. You will always have to train the model again, using past data and the new data received and then use the model to predict.

Answer (score 1):

Independent of using platforms like Spark, there are some very good techniques(for ex. non-negative matrix factorization) of link prediction which predicts link between 2 sets. 
Other very effective(and good) techniques of recommendations are:-
1. Thompson Sampling, 2.MAB (Multi Arm Bandits). A lot depends on the raw dataset. How is your raw dataset distributed. I would recommend to apply above methods on 5% raw dataset, build a hypothesis, use A/B testing, predicts links and move forward.

Again, all these techniques are independent of platform. I would also recommend of moving from scratch instead of using platforms like spark which are only useful for large datasets. You can always move to these platforms in future for scalability.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks. I will try them ASAP and let you know. :)